What can be the technical limit of CPUs?
My question is quite theoretical, first there is a CPU which can be overclocked at any extent and a normal working temperature is maintained in CPU (80oC)
Case 1:
I am providing it with power enough to satisfy the P=C∗V^2∗F this equation so will the CPU last for its expected lifetime.
Case 2:
I am providing it with power same as before over clocking now I decreased current such that
(C1*F1)/F2 = C2 where c1 and f1 are current and frequency of CPU before overclocking and c2 and f2 are current and frequency of CPU after overclocking will the CPU work.
EDIT:
Input current, voltage and frequency are directly controlled by custom electronic system.

Most modern CPUs use complex DVFS and multiple power domains. It will "work", but in a completely different performance envelope. It is tough to answer this question unless you specify more constraints, a specific model, etc.

How would you control input current?

Are you indeed capable to dictate all three of Input current, voltage and frequency?

As such the question does not make a lot of sense: "will the CPU last for its expected lifetime" cannot even be guaranteed under normal conditions.  And there is no standard how expected lifetimes may change under untested/unguaranteed conditions.

I’m voting to close this question because this question has been asked before in a different form. The original question was deleted and a new one asked which is circumventing the question system. If the question is off topic, then don't open a new question. If the question is on topic then edit the original question.

If you have a temperature target, then you can forget the electrical aspects.
What counts is the thermal conductivity of the cooling path, which will a chain of individual resistances, expressed in watts per degree of temperature difference.
Typically, the first element in that chain will be conductive because you do not want mechanical forces to act on the CPU die directly, and it is likely to be the weakest conductor because it also needs to be an electrical insulator, which rules out a few of the better thermal conductors.
The difference between the target temperature and the lowest limit of the operating temperature range is the theoretical limit, and multiplying it with the thermal conductivity will give the theoretical limit for the electrical power that the CPU can convert into heat.
In practice, the limit is a lot lower, because most people cool down to ambient, not the operating temperature limit, and further elements in the cooling chain also add more resistance.
